# Trying to make a title left aligned in a minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, minipage

I have tried various different ways of attempting to implement this. I want a title and author flushed left and an image flushed right on the same level. However I am using 2 columns so I should use 'maketitle' rather than simply bypass it and enlarge some text.

I cannot seem to get the title and author to the left they act as if they are central.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{multicol} 

\begin{document}
\title{\fontsize{22pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{Title}}

\author
{
\Large
    \textsc{Name}\\[2mm]
    \large University \\
    \normalsize e@mail.com \\
    \vspace{-5mm}
}
\date{}


\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
    \maketitle{ \begin{flushleft}
    \title
    \author
    \end{flushleft}
    }
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{image}
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your usage of the titlage macros is obscure at best, afaik. At least, it doesn't work, because the titlage macros output centered text.

Comment: You should overthink that whole code. First of all, you can't use `\title`, `\author` and `\date` to output meta data. They are only able to collect the relevant information. (These get internally stored into macros caled `\@title` and so on.) Hence, you also should not hard-code stuff within meta markup, as you did in `\author` in your example. If you need to place more information on your titlepage and align it differently, please just use the `titlepage` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know, you don't *have* to use `\maketitle`.
Or you could `\renewcommand{\maketitle}...`.

[image: title page]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
{\fontsize{22pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{Title}}\\
\Large
\textsc{Name}\\[2mm]
\large University \\
\normalsize e@mail.com \\
\end{minipage}\hfill% push eveerything to the right
\raisebox{-9mm}{\includegraphics[scale=.28]{image}}

\end{document}
```